# g++ 4.2 inline assembly of SSE instructions wraps up user assembly code with aligned XMM register copy

Tags: c++, g++, sse, inline-assembly, memory-alignment

I have a function using inline assembly:

```
  vec8w x86_sse_ldvwu(const vec8w* m) { 
     vec8w rd; 
     asm("movdqu %[m],%[rd]" : [rd] "=x" (rd) : [m] "xm" (*m)); 
     return rd; 
  }
```

It gets compiled to the following assembly code:

```
  sub    $0x1c,%esp
  mov    0x24(%esp),%eax
  movdqa (%eax),%xmm0 
  movdqu %xmm0,%xmm0
  movdqa %xmm0,(%esp)
  movdqa (%esp),%xmm0
  add    $0x1c,%esp
  ret
```

The code isn't terribly efficient, but that isn't my concern. As you can see the inline assembler inserts a movdqa instruction copying from the address in %eax to xmm0. The problem is that the pointer vec8w* m is **not** 128 bytes aligned, so I get a seg fault when movdqa is being executed. 
My question is whether there is a way to instruct the inline assembler to use movdqu instead of movdqa (that it uses by default)? I tried to look for a workaround using SSE intrinsic functions for g++, but somehow I cannot find movdqu in xmmintrin.h file (where it should be declared, I suppose). 
Unfortunately, I cannot modify the code so that the function is always called for an **aligned** argument m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intrinsic that you are looking for is `_mm_loadu_si128`. It is defined in `emmintrin.h`. Which is SSE2. The `xmmintrin.h` header contains only SSE(1) instructions.

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_int_load.htm

`_mm_loadu_si128` will emit the `movdqu` instruction which you are looking for. It seems that's exactly what you are trying to accomplish with your inline assembly function. (a misaligned load)